# Permission Issues with Azure Managed Identity and Dynamics 365 CRM (C#)

Tags: c#, sharepoint, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, azure-managed-identity

Language: C# .NET6
Dynamics: 356 CRM (Cloud)
Integration: Azure Function (Timer)
RequestType: HttpClientFactory (Http Client)
Authentication: MSAL (Managed Identity)

Currently using Dynamics 365 CRM (Cloud Based) and Azure Functions to integrate with CRM-Sharepoint (Document and Document libraries). The azure function is using managed identities and has full system admin privileges. The auth method is the DefaultAzureCredential(). Note the same pattern does work with many other applications we have (managed identities and http client factory), so the code itself doesn't appear to be an issue. The code also works locally.

When run locally (Visual Studio), I am able to run the integration fine (query a case and the document location/documents, as well as upload a document to the case). However, when the function is run in azure, the token receives a Http 400 bad request with the following message:

{
"error": {
"code": "0x80040216",
"message": "At least 1 Claim must not be NULL, current claims are : nameid=;nii=urn:federation:microsoftonline "
}
}

If I take that same request and paste it in postman using a token generated from my Visual Studio managed identity, it works successfully.

I am unsure of what permission I am missing (either in Sharepoint, CRM, or Azure). I have tried a using an existing sharepoint integration app reg and it also got the same error when using the azure function identity token.

If anyone has any insight or ideas about what could be missing, that would be great.

1. Tried using managed identity for the azure function (failed)
2. Tried using Visual Studio identity for function (successful)
3. Tried using working azure app registration utilized for different sharepoint in azure (failed)
4. Attempted to use my azure ad account. Failed because it is MFA.